# C++/CLI equivalent of C#'s 'readonly' keyword

Tags: c++-cli

What's the C++/CLI equivalent of C#'s `readonly` keyword?

Specifically, how do you write a public or protected member of a C++/CLI class such that it is `readonly` when referenced from C#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Literal field versus constant variable in C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238078/literal-field-versus-constant-variable-in-c-cli)

Comment: @Hans The question is about `readonly`, not `const`. If I'd found anything relevant when searching for `readonly`, I wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I just found out (thanks to [Literal field versus constant variable in C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238078/literal-field-versus-constant-variable-in-c-cli)) that

- C# `const` is `literal` in C++/CLI, and
- C# `readonly` is `initonly` in C++/CLI