# C# "readonly" equivalent in C++?

Tags: c#, c++

I have a `c#` code, in this a variable present in a **class**.

```
public static readonly string str;
```

Now i am writing c++ code for this class. What i can use in c++ for this `static readonly` thing.

Comment: Chekc this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7469404/4827151 dont forget to upvote

Comment: Is this a native or CLR code?

Comment: @Desperado That only applies to c++/CLI

Comment: @Desperado Why ask a user with 1-rep to upvote. He can't...

Comment: @PatrickHofman sorry I didn't think about it, for courtesy only

Comment: One thing to note here is that the equivalent C++ type for many C# types would be something like `const std::shared_ptr<T>`. For reference types, `readonly` disallows referring to a new object, but does not disallow modifying the object being referred to. C++ `const` on a plain object will disallow the latter. I simply chose `shared_ptr` for reference counting semantics, which is one way of implementing garbage collection.

Comment: what is your intent? you avoid to change the value in runtime or in compile time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++/CLI equivalent of C#'s 'readonly' keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469224/c-cli-equivalent-of-cs-readonly-keyword)

Answer (score 4):

I thing you can use private member and make getter for it. Something like this

```cpp
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
  static std::string getStr() const { return str; }
private:
  static std::string str;
}
std::string Test::str = "initial value";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
static const std::string str = "Hello";//a is explicitly static
```

`const` says that the variable's name can't be used to modify its value.
`static` says that the variable is stored in static storage.

Comment: You can't. Read-only is not a constant. It is a field that can be set from the constructor or class declaration only.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, Although you can almost always initialize such a member in a C++ constructor initializer list, giving it behaviour similar to `readonly`.